# How to fix Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Satellite.v(3) near text: "module"; expecting ";"

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a code in Verilog (by adding 2 modules together) and upload it to FPGA. I wanna start an IR module with LCD 1602 module, I created a module and wrote the IR and LCD modules in the main module

```
module Satellite(clk, rs, rw, en,dat,rst_n,IR,led_cs,led_db)

    module lcd(clk, rs, rw, en,dat)  
            input clk;  
             output [7:0] dat; 
             output  rs,rw,en;
```

Comment: i did it because of one answer in this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704989/how-to-wire-two-modules-in-verilog

Comment: if you have any suggest solutions please tell me

Comment: you can fix it by adding `;` ... after the `)`.

Comment: added but it still broken and the same problem 
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Satellite.v(3) near text: "module";  expecting ";".

Comment: did you do for both modules? BTW, module in module is allowed in `system verilog` only. Verilog does not allow declaring module inside other modules. So, you need `endmodule` before the `module lcd`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with the code.

1. module declaration requires `;` after ports, like the following: `module abc(port1, port2,...);`
2. declaration of a module within a module is not allowed in verilog. The `module` ... `endmodule` structure must be stand-alone.

So, your code might look like the following:

```
module Satellite(clk, rs, rw, en,dat,rst_n,IR,led_cs,led_db);
    input clk;
    // ... define other ports

    // instantiate the module 'lcd'
    lcd lcd(clk, rs, rw, en, dat);

    // ... do something else
endmodule

module lcd(clk, rs, rw, en,dat);  
        input clk;  
         output [7:0] dat; 
         output  rs,rw,en;

    // ... do something here
endmodule
```

Comment: it's just part of the code and for your point number 2, i declared the module correctly

Comment: also i putted the " ; " at the end of the module

Comment: in this case you have to change your question so that it shows all the related code. I do not any longer understand what you are asking about.

Comment: //F
default:
  led_db=8'b1000_1110 ;
        
 endcase
in these lines it gaves me this Error

Comment: Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Satellite.v(248) near text: "endcase";  expecting ":", or ",".

Comment: you **cannot** use `;` after any of the `end...` statements. Please read a verilog tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

```
              reg  dis; 
              reg [0:0] led_cs;
              reg [7:0] led_db;
            .

            .

            .

case(led2)


                    8'b01101000: 
                        led_db=8'b1100_0000;        
                        dis="0";
                                    .

            .

            .
```

dat0:   begin  rs<=1; dat<=dis; next<=dat1; end

Comment: this is not an answer and it is not related to anything in the question.